# Binding form parameters from JSP to spring controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, data-binding

I know this is a question which has been asked before. I did look at those questions but I was still not able to resolve my problem and thus writing in on stackoverflow. I am trying to bind the form parameters from my form addArticles.jsp to the controller. On the controller when I do a system.out.println I only get the categoryId and do not get the categoryName. I am not sure what I am doing is incorrect and pretty amused.

addArticles.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Add Article</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h2>Create New Article</h2>
        <form:form action="/one2one/articles/save.do" method="POST" modelAttribute="command">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="id">Article ID</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="id" value="${article.id}"></form:input></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="title">Article Title</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="title" value="${article.title}"></form:input></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="description">Article Description:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="description" value="${article.description}" cssStyle="width: 150px;"></form:input></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="category.categoryId">Category Type</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:select path="category.categoryId" cssStyle="width: 150px;">
                            <option value="-1">Select a type</option>
                            <c:forEach items="${categories}" var="category">
                             <option <c:if test="${category.categoryName eq article.category.categoryName}">selected="selected"</c:if>
                             value="${category.categoryId}">${category.categoryName}</option>  
                             </c:forEach> 
                        </form:select>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="keywords">Article Keywords:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="keywords" value="${article.keywords}"></form:input></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="content">Article Content:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="content" value="${article.content}"></form:input></td>
                </tr>

       <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td><input type="submit" value="SAVE"/></td>
        </tr>

            </table>
        </form:form>

            </center>
</body>
</html>
```

ArticlesController.java

```
package com.java.bricks.controller;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.java.bricks.model.Article;
import com.java.bricks.model.Category;
import com.java.bricks.service.ArticleService;
import com.java.bricks.service.CategoryService;

@Controller("articlesController")
@RequestMapping(value="/articles")
public class ArticlesController {

    @Autowired
    private ArticleService articleService;

    @Autowired
    private CategoryService categoryService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/list", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView listArticles(@ModelAttribute("command") Article article, BindingResult bindingResult){

        Map<String,Object> model = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        model.put("articles", articleService.listArticles());
        return new ModelAndView("articlesList",model);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/add",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addArticle(@ModelAttribute("command") Article article, BindingResult bindingResult) {

        Map<String,Object> model = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        model.put("articles", articleService.listArticles());
        model.put("categories", categoryService.listCategories());
        return new ModelAndView("addArticle",model);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/save",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveArticle(@ModelAttribute("command") Article article, BindingResult bindingResult) {

        Map<String,Object> model = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println(article.getCategory());
        System.out.println(article.getCategory().getCategoryName());
        System.out.println(article.getCategory().getCategoryId());
        articleService.addArticle(article);
        model.put("articles",articleService.listArticles());
        return new ModelAndView("addArticle",model);
    }

}
```

when I click save the first 4 lines of the SOP statements are

System.out.println(article.getCategory());
output: Category [categoryId=29, categoryName=null]

System.out.println(article.getCategory().getCategoryName());
null

System.out.println(article.getCategory().getCategoryId())
29

I am not sure why the categoryName is not populated in the controller.

Article.java

```
package com.java.bricks.model;


public class Article {

    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String keywords;
    private String content;
    private Category category;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getKeywords() {
        return keywords;
    }
    public void setKeywords(String keywords) {
        this.keywords = keywords;
    }
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }
    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't going to get the category name in the form's content because the category's name is being used a the label for the option. Only the value gets bound. This is your binding `path="category.categoryId"`. You aren't binding anything to `path="category.categoryName"` so it's going to be null.

So in your controller you have to get the category by its ID. If you want to do some automatic custom conversion, that is a separate question.

[Here's a nice article on entity conversion.](https://www.isostech.com/blogs/software-development/easy-entities-spring-mvc/)

Comment: thanks man, this helped me a lot, actually i was trying some examples using spring mvc and hibernate and one to many mappings and it looks like I don't even need the category name. I was just being paranoid. but this explanation helped me a lot to move forward..

Comment: Awesome. Just so you know, a lot of people would say that you shouldn't even be binding front-end values directly to Hibernate entities. The MVC paradigm wants you to keep the model separate from the view. I use a hybrid approach where I have implemented a cache for reference data like your category that does a similar automatic conversion like outlined in the article I linked, but on a POJO that represents the front-end form. I think most front-end forms usually aren't a perfect mirror of one entity and that approach works well for me.